# Invalid argument supplied for foreach - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having an issue with my Virtual Private server. The VPS hosts 2 wordpress websites.
Since last week the server suddenly started to generate errors sometimes and both websites show the error below on the front-end. After restarting the Apache webserver it would be OK again for 1 or 2 days, but this time seems to be decreasing.

The error which is generated at the front-end is:

`"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/domainname/wp-includes/locale.php on line 117 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/domainname/wp-includes/locale.php on line 159
Error establishing a database connection"`

Contents of Locale.php: (nothing has been changed to this)

```
function init() {
    // The Weekdays
    $this->weekday[0] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Sunday');
    $this->weekday[1] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Monday');
    $this->weekday[2] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Tuesday');
    $this->weekday[3] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Wednesday');
    $this->weekday[4] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Thursday');
    $this->weekday[5] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Friday');
    $this->weekday[6] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Saturday');

    // The first letter of each day. The _%day%_initial suffix is a hack to make
    // sure the day initials are unique.
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Sunday')]    = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('S_Sunday_initial');
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Monday')]    = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('M_Monday_initial');
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Tuesday')]   = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('T_Tuesday_initial');
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Wednesday')] = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('W_Wednesday_initial');
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Thursday')]  = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('T_Thursday_initial');
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Friday')]    = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('F_Friday_initial');
    $this->weekday_initial[__('Saturday')]  = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('S_Saturday_initial');

    foreach ($this->weekday_initial as $weekday_ => $weekday_initial_) {
        $this->weekday_initial[$weekday_] = preg_replace('/_.+_initial$/', '', $weekday_initial_);
    }

    // Abbreviations for each day.
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Sunday')]    = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Sun');
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Monday')]    = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Mon');
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Tuesday')]   = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Tue');
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Wednesday')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Wed');
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Thursday')]  = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Thu');
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Friday')]    = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Fri');
    $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Saturday')]  = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Sat');

    // The Months
    $this->month['01'] = /* translators: month name */ __('January');
    $this->month['02'] = /* translators: month name */ __('February');
    $this->month['03'] = /* translators: month name */ __('March');
    $this->month['04'] = /* translators: month name */ __('April');
    $this->month['05'] = /* translators: month name */ __('May');
    $this->month['06'] = /* translators: month name */ __('June');
    $this->month['07'] = /* translators: month name */ __('July');
    $this->month['08'] = /* translators: month name */ __('August');
    $this->month['09'] = /* translators: month name */ __('September');
    $this->month['10'] = /* translators: month name */ __('October');
    $this->month['11'] = /* translators: month name */ __('November');
    $this->month['12'] = /* translators: month name */ __('December');

    // Abbreviations for each month. Uses the same hack as above to get around the
    // 'May' duplication.
    $this->month_abbrev[__('January')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Jan_January_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('February')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Feb_February_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('March')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Mar_March_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('April')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Apr_April_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('May')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('May_May_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('June')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Jun_June_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('July')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Jul_July_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('August')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Aug_August_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('September')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Sep_September_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('October')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Oct_October_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('November')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Nov_November_abbreviation');
    $this->month_abbrev[__('December')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Dec_December_abbreviation');

    foreach ($this->month_abbrev as $month_ => $month_abbrev_) {
        $this->month_abbrev[$month_] = preg_replace('/_.+_abbreviation$/', '', $month_abbrev_);
    }
```

I did not change anything in the php or mysql configuration, I have no clue why it has started behaving like this.

A temporary solution is to restart the httpd service, then everything would be fine for about 1 day, but it seems this time is decreasing to sometimes half of an hour.

At first I was thinking this issue is caused by Mysql. However, I configured a test tool to test mysql. At moments the VPS is suffering the issue, there is not a problem logging in into the database via the Mysql testtool.

To be honest, I am no php guru, hopefully somebody can put me on the right track. I've been troubleshooting and browsing forums by myself for some hours now, but I just don't now how to solve it.

If you need more info, please ask.
Many thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2):

Try to check them for is they are array or not before for loop like

```
 if(is_array($this->weekday_initial))
     foreach ($this->weekday_initial as $weekday_ => $weekday_initial_)
```

Comment: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" means whether we have passed an non-array or it may be DB issue...

Comment: First check at the select functionality from which you are getting data....then query and arguments you are passing....and also echo your sql query and run it in your DB ,if result not come then there is problem with your query

Comment: This is the contents of the Locale.php, lines 117 & 159 are in it, as well as the function:

Comment: show me the code for retriving "($this->weekday_initial"..??I will tell you

Comment: Ok, thx. I pasted the complete locale.php code for this function in the post, see above

Comment: Is the info I gave you enough or should I add more ?